# How to use a Swift protocol in ObjC Framework

Tags: protocols, swift

I just started to add Swift in my ObjC framework project because it is quite new, solver directly the gap to CloudKit and therefore maybe interesting to migrate to code step-by-step to Swift.

I tought i start with something simple, a protocol.

I did the following:
- I created a Swift file, and as you know there is no bridghing header for frameworks
- added my protocol in this file

and know i like to use it in my class's but well how? 
The solution for classes is simple, you just define a forward declaration. But was is about protocols?

It seems at them moment this is the last element which i have to migrate or do you know a approach?

Updated:

What i forget to mentioned, i marked the protocol @objc, because in general it is possible to use a Swift protocol in  ObjC but i just see at the moment restrictions in frameworks

Comment: In your Obj-C implementation (.m) file did you add `#import <##Your-Project-Name##>-Swift.h`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example in my project name `SwiftProtocol`:

**Renderable.swift**

```
@objc protocol Renderable
{
    @objc func render()
}
```

**Triangle.h**

```
#import "SwiftProtocol-Swift.h"    // This is very important!

@interface Triangle : NSObject <Renderable>

@end
```

**Triangle.m**

```
@implementation Triangle

- (void)render
{
   // Do some rendering
}

@end
```